# Why is "sauté" spelled with an accent and "repartee" not?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, diacritics

Why are these words spelled differently? They have the same sound at the end, right?

Comment: Welcome katie! Please punctuate your sentences properly. Also, is this a real question, or just a rant?

Comment: English is the perfect language, and I'll hear no more about it! ;)

Comment: By the way, *sauté* has but one *e*. *Repartee* is pronounced exactly as spelled, hence no accent.

Comment: Hi, sorryy for the puncutation, I"ll try to do better. :) It's a real question, I promise! Jimi, isn't it re-par-TAY not re-par-TEE? xoxoxo

Comment: 'Why isn't English more logical?' Both words are French, btw. -> http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=repartee / http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/saut%C3%A9.

Comment: Actually, they don't have the same sound at the end.  _Repartee_ ends with a much wider, longer vowel that _sauté_.

Comment: @katie, I've edited your question to conform more closely to our site guidelines (which specifically forbid rants disguised as questions). Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Tiago: repartee is not a French word :)

Comment: @katie: No worries :) It's usually pronounced *re-par-TEE*. *re-par-TAY* is not incorrect, only much, much less common, and only in American English, at that.

Comment: Perhaps this question would be better if it asked about the reasons for the different spellings of sauté and *matinée*.

Answer (score 11):

First, they don't sound the same at the end: ***sauté* ends with the same sound as *play***, *clay*, *foray*, *ballet* and *parquet* (for the last two: in their reference US pronunciation). ***Repartee* rhymes with *party* and *tee*!**

Onto the reasons: *repartee* comes from the French *repartie* (wit), which is pronunced the same (ends like *party*). Because it was adopted into English a long time ago (mid 17th century), its spelling has been anglicized: it evolved to match the pronunciation (think: *tee*).

*Sauté*, on the other hand, was adopted into English in the 19th century, and kept its original spelling. In French, it is pronunced with an open "e" sound at the end<sup>[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_front_unrounded_vowel)</sup>. The closest common sound in English is that of *play* and *clay*, so that's how it is pronounced.

---

***1:*** Apparently, the sound [e] doesn't exist outside of diphthongs in English. It is how they pronunce *bed* in Australia, [says Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_front_unrounded_vowel), and *cake* or *play* in some US dialects. It's used a lot in French ("é") and Italian (“va bene!”).

Comment: [e] is also present in many Scottish dialects, [among others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects).

Comment: The French word is actually *repartie*, with no accent. From “repartir” (go again, hence bounce off), not “répartir” (divide into parts).

Answer (score 8):

Because *repartee* is derived from the French *repartie*. There is no such word as *repartée* in French.

Comment: So it turns out that 'repartee' isn't the best example.  But taking 'payee' and 'sauté' for comparison: 'payee' has been in English long enough for its spelling and pronunciation to be fully Anglicized. 'Sauté' is a more recent adoption, so we spell it as the French do and pronounce it *approximately* as French.